# PHP CURL and scan a HTML file for a code

Tags: php

I've written a script to use CURL command to pull down a HTML file.  Once I pull the HTML file I want to extract bit of code out of it.  The code can be formatted like this.

```
A = Letters | 0 = numbers

A0000-00000-00000-00000-00000
```

I tried using this code

```
$searchfor = "/The software code:&nbsp;</STRONG>/";
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

$number = preg_grep($searchfor, $result);
foreach($number as $name) {
echo $name;
}
```

But getting no results with it.  Each time the software code will end up on line 78 on the page.  So if I extract that I can strip away the unwanted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = "asdfasrgarehdtehrjxx1234-12345-12345-12345-12345dfgfgnhfjnghfdj";
$matches = array();

preg_match("([A-Za-z][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{5})", $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

http://runnable.com/U8bi7kzjBq4I839h/php-find-string-with-regex

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$subject = "fs dfasfA0000-00000-00000-00000-00000fsfsf sad fsafC4533-23423-23424-23424-14144fsadf rwer wqF0094-13133-23412-23566-93946sdfshdfh";
$pattern = '/[A-Z]\d{4}-\d{5}-\d{5}-\d{5}-\d{5}/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => A0000-00000-00000-00000-00000 
    [1] => C4533-23423-23424-23424-14144 
    [2] => F0094-13133-23412-23566-93946 
)
```